# How to exclude amazon.com from a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

I've a specific Greasemonkey 1.8 /Firefox 20 script ([Auto-view spoiler boxes](https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/112636)) that works great on most sites,
but on amazon.com it destroys the layout.

I've tried to exclude amazon.com in the script settings, but it does not work.

Since amazon.com defaults to https:// I've set the exception like this in

User Script -> Auto-view spoiler boxes -> Options -> User settings:

Include Pages:

```
*http://*
```

Excluded Pages:

```
*https://*
```

Yet, the script still does work on every website (yes, I've cleared the browser cache).

On the script settings tab, the non-editable Included Pages section contains:

```
http://forums.kingdomofloathing.com/vb/showthread.php*
```

What I'm doing wrong? How to exclude amazon.com from a Greasemonkey script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference [the *include* and *exclude* rules for Greasemonkey](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Include_and_exclude_rules).

Don't use `*http://*` or `*https://*` the leading asterisk will yield unexpected results.  Also not all Amazon pages use https.

In the user settings, you can use
`http://*`
for the *Included Pages* and these four lines for the *Excluded Pages*:

```
http://amazon.com/*
http://*.amazon.com/*
https://amazon.com/*
https://*.amazon.com/*
```

---

## Or,

Erase all those user settings entries (the following won't work if you don't), and then use the *Edit this User Script* button/menu to change the script's metadata block to:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Auto-view spoiler boxes
// @namespace      http://userscripts.org/users/75549
// @description    Lets you skip clicking the Show button to view spoilers
// @include        http://*
// @exclude        /^https?://.*amazon\.com/?/
// ==/UserScript==
```

this lets you use Greasemonkey's regular expression matching to block all common Amazon (USA) addresses with one line.

---

---

Finally, not that it is best to avoid scripts that run on every page (`http://*`, etc.).  You'll have a faster, smoother experience if you just include the select pages where spoilers are an issue for you.

Comment: @KingRider, I just verified that it still works correctly on both GM 3.8 and GM 3.9.

Comment: Brock, tampermonkey? its using to chrome... lastest version

Comment: @KingRider, this question is tagged `Greasemonkey` and NOT `Tampermonkey`.  The OP also stated it was Firefox-specific.  I made no attempt to verify it works on both, and they do have a few differences. If you are sure you have a problem in *Tampermonkey*, you can open a new question.